# Como adicionar os botões de redes sociais

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso implementar os botões de redes sociais na minha aplicação(**FaceBook, LinkDin, YouTube**) `HTML/CSS/JavaScript` ? A maioria dos exemplo que eu achei são em `PHP`

Comment: você quer gerar botões de login?

Comment: @LuizSantos Não. Exemplo, o usuário clica em determiando botão e leva até o perfil da empresa de cada rede social

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode controlar o destino do click através do atributo `href` de uma âncora:

```html
<a href="https://pt-br.facebook.com/" style="display:table;padding:15px;background:url('http://www.iconninja.com/files/387/198/566/logo-social-fb-facebook-icon.svg') center;background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; "><a/><br>

<a href="https://br.linkedin.com/" style="display:table;padding:15px;background:url('http://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/linkedin-256.png') center;background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; "><a/><br>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" style="display:table;padding:15px;background:url('http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/902547949103841281/TmdokZcM_400x400.jpg') center;background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; "></a><br>
```

Existem diversas formas de realizar isso, esse é um exemplo simples.

Comment: Talvez só para ficar mais claro, por nós `href` o link da rede social `/perfil/MagicHat`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não tenho perfil no face:(....., mas conhece a máxima "Não dê o peixe, ensine a pescar"...?

Comment: estava me referindo à estrutura do link, não precisava ser real ;-) E sim, ultimamente eu me acostumei a dar o peixe frito e sem espinha

Comment: Ah.. eu tento correr disso, ainda sim agente acaba fazendo... Mas não é bom para quem quer aprender... 
Para falar a verdade eu não compreendi direito a questão e o meu interpretador tem o defeito de levar tudo ao pé da letra, sendo: " o usuário clica em determiando botão e leva até o perfil da empresa de cada rede social ", eu não sei exatamente ao que se refere...